# Writing includes for nested query in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join, activerecord, include

```
McEntity.joins(:member_credit_scores).includes(member_credit_ent_profile: :entity).where('sf.accountx.namex like ?', "% Time%").first
```

The above is my query. What i am expecting is

```
   mc_entity = {
    entity_sf_account_id: '0014PRD000fkeejAAA', 
    license_date: Date.today, portfolio_type_id: @portfolio_type.id,
    technology_description: "some technology_description", is_rejected: false, credit_value_rating_type_id: @credit_rating_type.id,
    member_credit_scores: {
      "0" => {
        avoided_expense: 151515, likelihood_of_assertion: 15, avoided_expense_notes: "some expense notes",
        likelihood_notes: "some likelihood notes", is_approved: true
      },
      "1" => {
        avoided_expense: 303030, likelihood_of_assertion: 30, avoided_expense_notes: "some random expense notes",
        likelihood_notes: "some random likelihood notes", is_approved: false
      }
    }
  }
```

But what i getting is McEntity with without any relations data.

```
   mc_entity = {
    entity_sf_account_id: '0014PRD000fkeejAAA', 
    license_date: Date.today, portfolio_type_id: @portfolio_type.id,
    technology_description: "some technology_description", is_rejected: false, credit_value_rating_type_id: @credit_rating_type.id,

  }
```

Comment: Did you tried `to_json` on your resultant object?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have relations data, but eager loading is working as it is not going to write query again when i retrieve sub records

Comment: Can you add it in question, that how it looks like?

Answer (score 1):

The data is actually being pulled, if you call the `#member_credit_scores` method it will return the data without doing a query, if you want it inside the json then you can pass that as a parameter

```
entity.to_json(methods: member_credit_scores)
```

This will call the method and add it to the json object.